# How to make transparent html elements unclickable?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm following a tutorial on a theme switcher. Here is the code:

```js
// DOM Elements

const darkButton = document.getElementById("dark");
const lightButton = document.getElementById("light");
const solarButton = document.getElementById("solar");
const body = document.body;

// Apply the cached theme on reload

const theme = 'light';
const isSolar = false;

if (theme) {
    body.classList.add(theme);
    isSolar && body.classList.add("solar");
}

// Button Event Handlers

darkButton.onclick = () => {
    body.classList.replace("light", "dark");
};

lightButton.onclick = () => {
    body.classList.replace("dark", "light");
};

solarButton.onclick = () => {
    if (body.classList.contains("solar")) {
        body.classList.remove("solar");
    } else {
        body.classList.add("solar");
    }
};
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
    color: currentColor;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

main {
    background-color: var(--bg);
    height: 90vh;
    color: var(--text);
    padding: 30px 25px 0px 25px;
}

#featured {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.grid-container {
    height: auto;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.basic-grid {
    display: grid;
    gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(240px, 1fr));
}

.card {
    background: var(--bg-card);
    padding: 7px 13px;
    color: var(--card-text);
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.card p {
    color: var(--card-text);
}

.card:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

:root {
    --gray0: #f8f8f8;
    --gray1: #dbe1e8;
    --gray2: #b2becd;
    --gray3: #6c7983;
    --gray4: #454e56;
    --gray5: #2a2e35;
    --gray6: #12181b;
    --blue: #0084a5;
    --purple: #a82dd1;
    --yellow: #fff565;
}

.light {
    --bg: var(--gray0);
    --bg-nav: linear-gradient(to right, var(--gray1), var(--gray3));
    --bg-dropdown: var(--gray0);
    --text: var(--gray6);
    --border-color: var(--blue);
    --bg-solar: var(--yellow);
    --bg-card: var(--gray4);
    --card-text: var(--gray1);
}

.dark {
    --bg: var(--gray5);
    --bg-nav: linear-gradient(to right, var(--gray5), var(--gray6));
    --bg-dropdown: var(--gray6);
    --text: var(--gray0);
    --border-color: var(--purple);
    --bg-solar: var(--blue);
    --bg-card: var(--gray2);
    --card-text: var(--gray5);
}

.solar {
    --gray0: #fbffd4;
    --gray1: #f7f8d0;
    --gray2: #b6f880;
    --gray3: #5ec72d;
    --gray4: #3ea565;
    --gray5: #005368;
    --gray6: #003d4c;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    height: 10vh;
    background: var(--bg-nav);
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.logo {
    color: var(--text);
    text-transform: capitalize;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 20;
}

.nav-links {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 50%;
}

.nav-links a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--text);
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.nav-links li {
    list-style: none;
}

.burger {
    display: none;
}

.burger div {
    width: 25px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: var(--burger-color);
    margin: 6px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.contact {
    background-color: rgb(37, 192, 192);
    padding: 8px 30px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: var(--text);
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.contact:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    background: var(--bg-dropdown);
    border-top: 2px solid var(--border-color);

    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;

    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    height: 3rem;
    margin-top: 1.22rem;
    padding: 0.5rem;

    box-shadow: rgba(2, 8, 20, 0.1) 0px 0.175em 0.5em;
    transform: translateX(-40%);

    transition: opacity 0.15s ease-out;
}

.hasDropdown:focus-within .dropdown {
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.dropdown-item a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    size: 0.7rem;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.dropdown-item a::before {
    content: " ";
    border: 2px solid var(--border-color);
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class="logo">
        Jeno
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-links">
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="hasDropdown">
            <a href="#">Theme</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li class="dropdown-item">
                    <a id="light" href="#">light</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown-item">
                    <a id="dark" href="#">dark</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown-item">
                    <a id="solar" href="#">solarize</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <button class="contact">Contact</button>
    </ul>
    <div class="burger">
        <div class="line1"></div>
        <div class="line2"></div>
        <div class="line3"></div>
    </div>
</nav>
<main>
</main>
```

I thought the `position: absoloute;` fixed this, but it doesn't

Under the theme drop down, you can still click the theme buttons even when it is closed. Is there anyway to fix this?

It doesn't work properly in the snippet, but it works on codepen: https://codepen.io/ksaeidnia0/pen/VwvrEBr.

Comment: Include the relevant code in your question. You should not link to an external site for your question contents since that site can change or go missing and make this question useless to those looking for it later.

Comment: Is that better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `display` property. When you hide the `.dropdown` class `display: none;` when you show it again use `display: block;` or something.

Answer (score 0):

add `visibility: hidden;` to `ul` wrap with class `dropdown`

Answer (score 0):

Using the `display` attribute you can control whether elements are shown. What you had just changed the `ul` lists's opacity which doesn't remove it from the page - it just makes it invisible but still there.  Try this in your css:

```
.hasDropdown .dropdown {
  display: none;
}

.hasDropdown:focus-within .dropdown {
  display: flex;
}
```

This tells it to not display when there's no focus and to display if there is.

Answer (score 0):

You are hiding dropdown elements with `opacity`, which only makes these HTML elements **transparent** and they **remain interactive**. 
Instead of opacity you may use `display` or `visibility`, but then you lose your animation.

`Display` is not an **animatable CSS property**, so you could use `height` or `visibility`. 
 The latter has discrete, rather than continuous values, therefore you cannot animate it *smoothly*. 
What you can do is to animate `height` with delay. This way the bug is gone, but behaviour is still the same.

I increased animation time, so that it is more noticeable.

**Changes**:

```
.dropdown {
    transition-delay: 1s;
    transition-property: height;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-out, height 0s;

    opacity:0;
    height: 0;
    padding: 0;

    display: flex;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.hasDropdown:focus-within .dropdown {
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    height: 3rem;
    pointer-events: auto;
}
```

```js
// DOM Elements

const darkButton = document.getElementById("dark");
const lightButton = document.getElementById("light");
const solarButton = document.getElementById("solar");
const body = document.body;

// Apply the cached theme on reload

const theme = 'light';
const isSolar = false;

if (theme) {
    body.classList.add(theme);
    isSolar && body.classList.add("solar");
}

// Button Event Handlers

darkButton.onclick = () => {
    body.classList.replace("light", "dark");
};

lightButton.onclick = () => {
    body.classList.replace("dark", "light");
};

solarButton.onclick = () => {
    if (body.classList.contains("solar")) {
        body.classList.remove("solar");
    } else {
        body.classList.add("solar");
    }
};
```

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
    color: currentColor;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

main {
    background-color: var(--bg);
    height: 90vh;
    color: var(--text);
    padding: 30px 25px 0px 25px;
}

#featured {
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.grid-container {
    height: auto;
    width: 75%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.basic-grid {
    display: grid;
    gap: 1rem;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(240px, 1fr));
}

.card {
    background: var(--bg-card);
    padding: 7px 13px;
    color: var(--card-text);
    border-radius: 5px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

.card p {
    color: var(--card-text);
}

.card:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform: scale(1.05);
}

:root {
    --gray0: #f8f8f8;
    --gray1: #dbe1e8;
    --gray2: #b2becd;
    --gray3: #6c7983;
    --gray4: #454e56;
    --gray5: #2a2e35;
    --gray6: #12181b;
    --blue: #0084a5;
    --purple: #a82dd1;
    --yellow: #fff565;
}

.light {
    --bg: var(--gray0);
    --bg-nav: linear-gradient(to right, var(--gray1), var(--gray3));
    --bg-dropdown: var(--gray0);
    --text: var(--gray6);
    --border-color: var(--blue);
    --bg-solar: var(--yellow);
    --bg-card: var(--gray4);
    --card-text: var(--gray1);
}

.dark {
    --bg: var(--gray5);
    --bg-nav: linear-gradient(to right, var(--gray5), var(--gray6));
    --bg-dropdown: var(--gray6);
    --text: var(--gray0);
    --border-color: var(--purple);
    --bg-solar: var(--blue);
    --bg-card: var(--gray2);
    --card-text: var(--gray5);
}

.solar {
    --gray0: #fbffd4;
    --gray1: #f7f8d0;
    --gray2: #b6f880;
    --gray3: #5ec72d;
    --gray4: #3ea565;
    --gray5: #005368;
    --gray6: #003d4c;
}

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    height: 10vh;
    background: var(--bg-nav);
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.logo {
    color: var(--text);
    text-transform: capitalize;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 20;
}

.nav-links {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 50%;
}

.nav-links a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--text);
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.nav-links li {
    list-style: none;
}

.burger {
    display: none;
}

.burger div {
    width: 25px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: var(--burger-color);
    margin: 6px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.contact {
    background-color: rgb(37, 192, 192);
    padding: 8px 30px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: var(--text);
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.contact:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.dropdown {
    transition-delay: 1s;
    transition-property: height;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-out, height 0s;
   
  
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    opacity:0;
    z-index: 2;
    background: var(--bg-dropdown);
    border-top: 2px solid var(--border-color);

    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;

    height: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin-top: 1.22rem;
    padding: 0;

    overflow: hidden;

    box-shadow: rgba(2, 8, 20, 0.1) 0px 0.175em 0.5em;
    transform: translateX(-40%);

    
}

.hasDropdown:focus-within .dropdown {
    border-top: 2px solid var(--border-color);
    opacity: 1;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    height: 3rem;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.dropdown-item a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    size: 0.7rem;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.dropdown-item a::before {
    content: " ";
    border: 2px solid var(--border-color);
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class="logo">
        Jeno
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-links">
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="hasDropdown">
            <a href="#">Theme</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li class="dropdown-item">
                    <a id="light" href="#">light</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown-item">
                    <a id="dark" href="#">dark</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown-item">
                    <a id="solar" href="#">solarize</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <button class="contact">Contact</button>
    </ul>
    <div class="burger">
        <div class="line1"></div>
        <div class="line2"></div>
        <div class="line3"></div>
    </div>
</nav>
<main>
</main>
```